# V-model is not accessible when using :Value on my APP (Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I'm creating a test app and I'm trying to set the default value of the field by calculation of other fields so this is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="sc table-input" v-model="staff['all_total']" :value="(staff.salary + Number(staff['overtime']) + Number(staff['educational']) + Number(staff['finance']) + Number(staff['macul']))" />
```

By this, I want to combine four fields (overtime + educational + finance + macul) values and add it to another field called 'all_total' then the 'all_total' also will be used for some other calculations but it's all working the only problem is I don't have access to 'all_total' anymore if I remove the property of ':value' I can't access the 'all_total' v-model if I add ':value' then I can't access. Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` is just a syntax sugar, which means when you write:

```
<input v-model="staff['all_total']" />
```

you are getting:

```
<input :value="staff['all_total']" @input="staff['all_total'] = $event.target.value"/>
```

So when you use both `v-model` and `:value` in your code, `:value` will be used and you will not get access to `staff['all_total']`.

If your goal is to prepopulate `staff['all_total']`, it's better to do it in code, probably `mounted`. If your goal is to just show some composed value, which is based on those 4 fields, use `computed` instead.

Comment: you are right
but I do this for a list of users and every use should get the total calculated of those four fields.

Comment: image link= https://ibb.co/Xzg17tG

Comment: in this table each column is an input field